# Installing rjags on Fedora 33

Tags: jags, rjags

I'm trying to install rjags on a Fedora 33 system running R 4.0.3.  I've installed JAGS 4.3.0 from source and can run the software from the command line, but when I try to install the package in R, I get this error:

```
checking version of JAGS library... link error
configure: error: Runtime link error: See the INSTALL file for help
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rjags’
```

I've followed [this](https://cddesjardins.wordpress.com/2010/05/30/jags-and-rjags-for-fedora-13-64-bit/) tutorial for building an installing on Fedora, and have all the expected directories under /usr/local/lib64, but get the same errors.

I've also followed [this](http://yusung.blogspot.com/2009/01/install-jags-and-rjags-in-fedora.html) tutorial which specifies the various file locations - also get the same errors.

Finally, I found [this](https://github.com/cran/rjags/blob/master/INSTALL) which gives some options under section 3, but none of those worked.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue - did you ever find an answer?

Comment: I did not.  I started using Stan instead.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled across a solution here that seems to work:
https://github.com/cran/rjags/blob/master/INSTALL

Installing `rjags` with the argument below seems to have worked:

```
> install.packages("rjags", configure.args="--enable-rpath")
```

Answer (score 0):

R is looking for jags in the `--prefix=/usr`. Download the latest jags [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/). Try installing jags and rjags like this:

```
sudo install -d -o $USER -g $USER -m 775 /usr/src/jags
tar xvf ~/Downloads/JAGS-4.3.2.tar.gz -C /usr/src/jags --strip-components=1
cd /usr/src/jags
./configure --prefix=/usr
make -j $(nproc)
sudo make install
```

Now install the `rjags` R package:

```
R -e 'install.packages(c("rjags"))'
```